# what risk response type can be used to respond to a threat and an opportunity?

Tags: prince2

On a sample Prince2 exam online, I found that it says what risk response type can be used to respond to a threat and an opportunity. And the answer given is Share.

According to the diagram here, there is no single risk response type for both threat and opportunity. What am I not understanding correctly?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39592/discussion-on-question-by-hello-universe-what-risk-response-type-can-be-used-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I found the following online that explain this nicely

> Share is both a response for threats and opportunities. Share is very
>   common in customer/supplier projects where both parties share the gain
>   if the costs are less than the planned costs and share the loss, too,
>   if the costs are exceeded.
>
> **Example:** In the concert example, suppose you have a supplier that provides VIP toilet facilities and people are charged €1 for each
>   service. There is a certain fixed cost that you must pay to provide
>   this service and you agree with the supplier to share the profits if
>   the revenue is above this fixed cost amount and share the losses if it
>   is below this amount.